# React-redux upgrade from 1.8.0 to 1.9.3

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, upgrade, react-redux-i18n

After upgrading react-redux from 1.8.0 to 1.9.3 , string formatting for dropdown item is changed , Test Values is getting translated as test_values , why? How to change this string formatting?

After upgrading react-redux from 1.8.0 to 1.9.3 , string formatting for dropdown item is changed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.